# Button dosent change opacity of div after clicking (closed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that is on a website. This button should change the opacity of one of the divs from 100 to 0 to make it "invissible". 
 
Here is my button that i use

```
<button id="buttonfade" onclick="fadebutton()">
```

Here is my function that should update the div when the button is clicked

```
function fadebutton() { document.getElementById('fadediv').style.opacity = '0';}
```

And the div has the id fadediv. Am I doing something wrong or why isnt it changing the opacity of the div. 
Thx for the help

Comment: What kind of a "_subpage_" you have? Is the button on the same page as the div?

Comment: If you  do `document.getElementById('fadediv').style.opacity = '0';` in the console, does it work?

Comment: The button and the div are on the same page

Comment: Is your `<button>` inside a `<form>`?

Comment: @connexo yes it works in console

Comment: Provide a _proper_ [mre] of such issues, not just snippets / single lines of code, that lack the necessary context.

Comment: Please add the `type="button"` attribute to your `button` and try again.

Comment: And @connexo it is not inside a form

Comment: And you also have only **one** element with `id="fadediv"`?

Comment: Your code seems reasonable and should work. Without further details, preferrably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Yeah there is only 1 element with that id

Comment: Are you having any errors in the console after clicking the button? Have you checked whether that div after clicking has `style="opacity: 0"`?

Comment: Yes i have 1 Error `Uncaught ReferenceError: fadebutton is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):423)`

Comment: And if I dot the `document.getElementById('fadediv').style.opacity = '0';` in the console it works and the dive has the  `style="opacity: 0"`

Comment: Are you accessing fadeButton from anywhere else also other than the click event?

Comment: No i  am not only for the click event

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('buttonfade').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('fadediv').style.opacity = '0';
});
```

Comment: i dont think so, you need to add `()` like `onclick="fadebutton()"` to call a function

Comment: lmao yeah sorry, I just remembered it from w3schools and doubled checked for myself now, you're right

Answer (score 0):

So i found out why the Code didnt work. The position of the function was wrong so it couldnt be reached. I changed the position where it is and now it works. 
But i am so thankfull for all the help you guys provided

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
document.getElementById('fadediv')
```

To

```
document.getElementById('buttonfade')
```

Comment: But then my button whould get the opacity 0 and not the div. Or am I wrong?

Comment: no this is not what he wanted, your code will change the opacity of the button. he wanted to change the opacity of a `div` not the button

Comment: @MichaelKrapf yeah you are right he misunderstood the question